# Naming of Wear OS module of existing Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, module, wear-os, google-play-console

I am developing a Wear OS application of existing Android Application. I created Wear OS module with different app, module and package name in Android Studio of existing Android application's project. Here is the naming comparison.

- App name: for Wear OS is `wear`, for Android is `android`
- Module name: for Wear OS is `wear`, for Android is `android`
- Package name: for Wear OS is `com.example.wear`, for Android is `com.example.android`

Now when I am distributing the Wear OS on existing Android app I am getting error in Play Console.

- If I am using new key store for Wear OS app I get:

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your
> App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your
> App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with
> fingerprint:
>
> SHA1:
>
> but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has
> fingerprint:
>
> SHA1:

- If I am using key of existing Android application for Wear OS app I get:

> Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name
> com.example.android

Then I tried to rename folder name of Wear Os app the Android Studio prompts the error:

> File '...\com\example\android' already exists

After that, I tried to change `namespace` and `applicationId` values inside the app level (Wear OS app) gradle file from `com.example.wear` to `com.example.android` and after run the app I get:

> Execution failed for task ':wear:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.androd'

I would like to get information about the correct naming of app, module and package when creating new module for Wear OS of an existing Android application. Also, please provide solution how to change the incorrect naming to correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The Wear and Android apps must have the same signing key and package name.

See https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/packaging#specifying-app-as-standalone

> Note: If your Wear app has an accompanying phone app, you must use the same package name for the two apps.

Longer instructions are here https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-wear